Are covering spaces "classified" by a 2-dimensional CW complex?
Principal $G$-bundles are classified by maps into the classifying space $BG$:
$$\mathsf{PFB}_B(G)\simeq [B,BG].$$
When $G$ is discrete, $BG=K(G,1)$ is an Eilenbeg-MacLane space, and a principal $G$-bundle is simply a regular covering space whose deck transformation group is $G$. Thus
$$\mathsf{RegCov}_B(G)\simeq [B,K(G,1)].$$
Furthermore, for every discrete group $G$ it is easy to construct a 2-dimensional CW-complex called $X_G$ such that $\pi_1(X_G)=G$. It is a bouquet of circles corresponding to generators of $G$ with 2-cells attached to loops that correspond to relations on $G$. As an example, $X_{\mathbb{Z}_2}=\mathbb{R}P^2$. Therefore $K(G,1)$ can be seen as the first Postnikov truncation of $X_G$, and can be constructed out of $X_G$ by attaching cells in dimension 3 and higher. Thus $X_G$ is the 2-skeleton of $K(G,1)$.
Question: Intuitively it would seem that any map into $K(G,1)$ should be homotopic to a map into the 2-skeleton $X_G$. Is this true? And is it true that $\mathsf{RegCov}_B(G)\simeq [B,X_G]$? And does this classification have any connection with the standard classification theorem for covering spaces?

I think you should have something like $[B, K(G, 1)] \cong \operatorname{Hom}_\mathrm{Grp}(\pi_1(B), G)$ (certainly that's true if $G$ is abelian via cohomology, but you should be able to construct explicit maps as well by building models for the domain and codomain based on the same presentation of $\pi_1(B)$), so in particular for each normal subgroup $N \leq \pi_1(B)$ you get a covering from $(\pi_1(B) \to \pi_1(B) / N) \in \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(B), \pi_1(B) / N)$. Letting $N$ range, you should recover all regular coverings.

In this sense you recover the standard classification theorem for regular coverings (obviously you can do no better) by reducing it to a statement about (kernels of surjective) group homomorphisms with domain $\pi_1(B)$. (Is this roughly what you intended?)

@BenSteffan yeah this sounds like what I'm looking for. Can I say that this is a statement about representability of the first Čech cohomology with coefficients in a nonabelian group?

I don't know much about Čech cohomology, but judging from this answer the answer's probably "yes," provided that you restrict yourself to, say, $B$'s that have the homotopy type of a CW-complex (seeing as Čech cohomology does not respect weak equivalences).

@BenSteffan ah, awesome, thank you.

Consider the identity map from $\mathbb{RP}^\infty = K(\mathbb{Z}/2, 1)$ to itself. This map is not homotopic to a map into the 2-skeleton, since it's non-trivial on higher homology.

ok thanks. Does this way of classifying coverings via $K(G,1)$ have any relation to the classic classification result?
